# Display SMTP message to user prior to sending in .Net

Tags: smtp, mapi

When using MAPI the send command has parameters to display a login and the mail dialog prior to sending. For instance: mapiMessage.Send(MapiSendMailFlags.LogonUI | MapiSendMailFlags.Dialog);

Does anyone know of a way to do this for the SMTP Send command in .Net 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Can't do that - UI is your responsibility.
In case of Simple MAPI, the UI comes form whatever application that registered itself as the default Simple MAPI provider.